# Running Google App Engine PHP on Windows

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I keep getting **Syntax Error: unexpected character after line continuation character** when I try to start the localhost server with the following command:

google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="C:\Computer Science\PHP\php\php-cgi.exe" "C:\Computer Science\PHP\helloworld"

What's wrong?

My app.yaml:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php
```

My helloworld.py

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello, World!';
?>
```

My directories

```
    /PHP
       /php
          /php-cgi.exe
       /helloworld
       /google_appengine
```

Edit:
I have ran my app using the google app engine launcher, with php sdk and an extra command line flag in the launch settings:
`--php_executable_path=C:\Computer Science\PHP\php\php-cgi.exe`. The server crashed.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of the error you see when you run google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="C:\Computer Science\PHP\php\php-cgi.exe" "C:\Computer Science\PHP\helloworld" from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

user2481064 use the windows CMD, make sure you're in the same path as your google app engine sdk, i basically put my GAE SDK and application in the same path. Here it is:

1. Open your windows cmd, make sure you're in the same directory as your sdk.
2. Type: "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" --port=9999 --php_executable_path="fullpath\php-cgi.exe" "helloworld/"
3. If you have another local server like xampp or wamp,make sure you use the --port command to select another listening port as shown above.
   4.Press enter and you should have your helloworld script working.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I too got stuck with this or the other error "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator". Things got better when I stoppped using the Python shell but use the Windows cmd shell.

For my environment, the command I arrive at is

```
 "google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" --php_executable_path="\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-10\php\php-cgi.exe" "helloworld/"
```

(The direction of some of the slashes can be important if you later use parts of the command for separate investigation/diagnose in Windows.) Wow the engine starts despite various errors. At the webbrowser, I was able to see the localhost equivalent of the dashboard at localhost:8000/instances (force-redirected from localhost:8000) BUT the app itself at localhost:8080 (that's 8080) just shows
' "BitNami/rubystack-1.9.3-10/apache2/cgi-bin/php-cgi.exe -v" returned an error [-1072365564] '

Separately running

```
BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-10\apache2\cgi-bin\php-cgi.exe -v
```

reports my version of PHP is 5.4.15.  I am not sure if installing a an additional clean PHP will help. Or perhaps I should move on & push the app.

Comment: The browser says "This webpage is not available" on localhost:8080. Is there something wrong with my helloworld.php or app.yaml? Should the command line return anything when the server starts? I just have dev_appserver.py poped up and no other information provided.